# Excel UDF that makes network calls: how to improve performance

Tags: vba, excel, xll

I've written an excel udf that makes calls to a web api and I'd like to improve overall performance when function values are refreshed by bundling together web api calls instead of having each instance of the function make an independent call. I was thinking that when a data refresh is triggered I could count the number of instances of my udf within the open workbook, gather identifiers for the data that needs updating and only when my counter reaches the number of udf instances, execute the web api calls. Any suggestions as to more effective approaches?

Comment: Help us to help you.  **Post your current code**.

Comment: Currently I was not looking for support on writing code, I was trying to identify alternatives to implement the most convincing one, Not being certain of my idea, I've not yet started writing any code.

Comment: "I've written an excel udf", "I've not yet started writing any code" - huh?

Comment: It looks like people here on stack overflow have substituted the desire to help others with the desire to catch others in fault. Why is that? Yes, I've written a udf and yes, I've not yet written any code to optimize calls to the web api. Now each instance of my function in a workbook generates a dedicated web api call, something that I'd like to change and optimize if possible.

Comment: It is hard to help you optimise some code without seeing the code.  As suggested by @Gary'sStudent post your current code so that we can help you.  Even helping you decide on an appropriate **method** to improve performance would require us to be able to see how your code is designed to work.  (And requests for performance improvements should really be posted to Code Review rather than to Stack Overflow.)

Comment: What technology do you use ? VBA ? Excel C ? COM/RTD ?

Comment: UDF in C++. I was evaluating .NET especially because I'd like to have tooltips which Excel-DNA implements and which I believe are not built-in is using the Excel XLL SDK.

Answer (score 0):

My Excel-DNA based Addin [1] makes HTTP GET requests to quandl.com and tiingo.com, and also opens websockets to tiingo.com for real time updates. The HTTP GET requests are passed to a background worker thread where they're handled synchronously, and the results are cached. Simple worksheet functions pull the results from the cache into cells. The websocket updates are pushed into cells by RTD. All the source is on github [1]. If you're coding in C# I recommend Excel-DNA [2].

[1] https://github.com/SpreadServe/SSAddin

[2] https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna

Comment: So if I got you correctly, you have worker threads that in the background retrieve data from your sources and UDFs simply update on a timely basis your worksheets with data that is already available locally.

What I was thinking of doing was instead to have UDFs populate some sort of list with what data needs to be retrieved and I would go and fetch data only when all UDFs have "posted" in this list. To have this work correctly I would however need to know exactly how many UDFs are used in the excel worksheets.

Any comment on my idea?

Answer (score 0):

@noplace: in the past I have implemented an XLL that tracked UDF invocations by a worksheet. The worksheet was calculating options prices in response to real time market data, and I needed to make sure that all calcs were complete before allowing the next market data triggered calc cycle to start. More generally, the issue you'll face is that Excel's dependency graph engine, which determines the timing and order of UDF invocation, is a black box. So you can't make assumptions about timing and order. So I suggest you have two sets of UDFs. The first set populates your list, and primes the background data collection. Data collection results go into a cache in your code. The second set of UDFs pull data from the cache. You may want to make these volatile, or possibly use trigger parameters so you can control their invocation. In SSAddin I use RTD to push triggers back into the spreadsheet which can then cause invocation of the cache reading UDFs. All this is coded in the SSAddin link I provided above.

Comment: I believe yours is a perfect example to reason on. Wanting to optimize network calls I'd want to bundle retrieving updated data for all requested market symbols. I see a set of scenarios I should be able to handle: (1) adding a new UDF invocation (and the need here is to understand if the referenced market symbol is new or already in your list), (2) removal of a UDF invocation (and the need here is to understand if this was the last reference to the symbol so that it may be removed from your list), (3) opening of a saved worksheet with invocations to your UDFs. I'll look into your add-in, thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying I have duplicates, then stop that!  Have a single sheet whose role would be the make the network calls once and then other uses in your workbook can make reference to the results.

One can calculate sheets one at a time, and I'd do so in this case, or at least recalculate the network api sheet first before recalculating whole workbook.

Comment: It might not make sense but you could have duplicates even in the same sheet. My intent here was to optimize network traffic but even more optimize server side workload avoiding multiple requests coming from the same excel client for the same data.